# Can't find the chart.js v2 docs

Tags: chart.js

http://www.chartjs.org/ displays the old documentation of chartjs.

I think the following link was suppose to be the new documenation but it 404's.
http://nnnick.github.io/Chart.js/docs-v2/

Does someone has a link to the new documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is also hosted in GitHub. So irrespective of where it is actually hosted you can get the content from the relevant folder. Currently it is https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/tree/gh-pages/_doc-parts-v2

**Edit**

Just noticed that the main site (http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) now points to the new documentation